Where are milestone builds of the spring-boot gradle plugin stored?
I want to try out the milestone release of spring-boot: 3.4.0-MC2. In order to get milestone versions of spring boot, I added a separate maven repository, and that works for the java artifacts:
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}

I've always kept the spring-boot gradle plugin on the same version as the spring release. I can't figure out where or if the org.springframework.boot gradle plugin exists at version 3.4.0-MC2, and which repository to use to download it.

They are stored in the same place :)
You need to add the repositories separately in the settings.gradle file like so:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
        }
    }
}

Full example (which builds for me): https://github.com/willb611/hello-world-spring-boot-gradle/pull/1/files
Edit: if in doubt, you can find list of versions available at different repositories (i.e. spring milestone repository) here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot?repo=springio-milestone
